# Find unique element in an arraylist error

Tags: java, arraylist

Im new to array list. I have a program where I want to find unique cities. I use for loop to use this but it doesn't seem to display what I want it to be. May I know where did I went wrong?

```
run:
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Malaysia
Enter size of city: Medium
Enter postal code: 132222
___________________________________________
List Of Unique Cities: 
Malaysia,Singapore,Singapore,Singapore,Malaysia,Singapore,
```

---

I want it to print like this

```
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Singapore
Enter size of city: Small
Enter postal code: 132115
___________________________________________
Enter name of city: Malaysia
Enter size of city: Medium
Enter postal code: 132222
___________________________________________
List Of Unique Cities: 
Malaysia,Singapore,
```

---

```
public class TravellingApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        SalesPerson s1 = new SalesPerson();

        for(int j=1; j<=20; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter name of city: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter size of city: ");
            String size = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter postal code: ");
            int postalCode = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("___________________________________________");



            City c1 = new City(name, size, postalCode);
            s1.addCity(c1);

        }
        System.out.println("List Of Unique Cities: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.returnListOfCities().size(); i++) 
        {
            for (int k = s1.returnListOfCities().size() - 1; k >= i; k--) 
            {
                if (s1.returnListOfCities().get(i).equals(s1.returnListOfCities().get(k)))
                {
                    s1.returnListOfCities().remove(s1.returnListOfCities().get(i));
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(s1.returnListOfCities().get(k) + ",");

            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: *it doesn't seem to display what I want it to*. Well, what is it displaying and what did you want it to? Or did you want us to guess and offer a solution to an imagined problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `City` class must override the method `equals()` to get your desired behavior of `equals()` (the default just tests the object reference.  This behavior is not what you want).

By the way, you don't even need to do this duplicate detection.  Just switch to use the interface `Set`, and it can guarantee that all elements in the set is unique.  If you don't care about order, then you can use the implementation `HashSet` as the implementation.  So, implement `City#hashCode()` and then switch to use this line:

```
Set<City> s1 = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Application of Data Structure HashSet +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your original list untouched, and build a new one with the distinct values, here is how you can do using java8 streams :

```
List<City> allCities = s1.returnListOfCities();
List<City> distinctCities = allCities.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As already said and explained, your `City` must override `equals()`.

Using stream, you can also pretty print your list like that :

```
System.out.println(allCities.stream().distinct().map(City::getName).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Or, if you cannot override `City` with `equals()` (let's say it's already defined to compare on postcode, but you want to compare on name), you can do :

```
System.out.println(allCities.stream().map(City::getName).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

In that case, the names are directly compared as String's.